# Variance components estimation in Poisson mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, poisson-regression

In the mixed Poisson regression model, with vector of random effects $w \sim N(0, \Sigma)$, how are the parameters in $\Sigma$ estimated? Is it the same REML method as in the linear mixed model?

Comment: What efforts have you made to figure this out?  And what software package are you interested in?  For example, proc glimmix in sas has very good documentation on how "REML" type estimation is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In generalized linear mixed models (GLMM), including linear mixed model, logistic mixed model, and Poisson mixed model, the covariance matrix of random effects ($\Sigma$) can all be estimated with maximum likelihood (ML) or restricted maximum likelihood (REML). The differences between these models are:

- the distribution of the outcome, i.e., normal, Bernoulli, or Poisson distribution;
- the link function between the mean of the outcome and the covariates,
  i.e., identity link, logit link, or log link function.

If your sample size is big enough, the ML estimate of the variance will also tend to be unbiased.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Randel. I am waiting the end on the bounty to attribute my vote.